# Non-isomorphic graphs with 2 vertices and 3 edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Are there any non-isomorphic graphs with 2 vertices and 3 edges? From my understanding of what non-isomorphic means, I don't think there are any, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this image answer your question?

[image]

Comment: Ohhh i get it now. I didn't think about loops. Thank you to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you allow both loops and multiple edges. If the vertices are $u$ and $v$, you can have: three edges between $u$ and $v$; two edges between $u$ and $v$ and a loop at one of the vertices; one edge between $u$ and $v$ and two loops at one vertex; one edge between $u$ and $v$ and a loop at each vertex; three loops at one vertex and no other edges; or one loop at one vertex and two loops at the other vertex.